# apache mod rewrite 301 get variables showing

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following for a page:

```
RewriteRule ^es/aprende-([^/]+)-online$ learn-language.php?learnLang=$1&lang=es [L]
```

My new page:

```
RewriteRule ^es/aprende-ingles-online$ learn-english-online.php?lang=es [L]
```

Now I want to do a 301 redirect on this page:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /es/aprende-inglés-online http://www.example.com/es/aprende-ingles-online
```

But when I go to the page the variables get carried on and appended to the url ?

```
learnLang=inglés&lang=es
```

I dont want this get variables to be added on, what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep redirect rule before your earlier internal rewrite rule and use `mod_rewrite` rules only:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^es/aprende-inglés-online/? /es/aprende-ingles-online [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^es/aprende-ingles-online$ learn-english-online.php?lang=es [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^es/aprende-([^/]+)-online$ learn-language.php?learnLang=$1&lang=es [L,QSA]
```